# Is it possible to deploy Kubernetes on a single web server?

Tags: kubernetes

Good afternoon!

In my study of Kubernetes, I got to the practice of deploying Kuber on the server. There are different deployment scenarios. I chose kubespray. Can you tell me if you can somehow deploy kuber on a host? Or is it necessary to create virtual machines, set up a network between them and only then deploy the cluster?

Comment: Kubernetes is not just "a webserver" you need a linux host with full ssh access to be able to administrate a kubernetes cluster. Get more familiar with the matter before you start.

Comment: @Marc It's understandable that it's not a web server. It's a container orchestrator. I asked if it is possible to deploy a single node cluster using kubespray.

Comment: Your title say something else. You can deploy a kubernetes "cluster" on just node. Dunno if its possible with kubespray. But even if its possible, its not best practice. Is ok for experiments, but not should not be used for production deploys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Node: `A node may be a virtual or physical machine, depending on the cluster. Each node is managed by the control plane and contains the services necessary to run Pods.`

You can deploy single Node Kubernetes

For local (development, test etc) purposes:

- minikube
- kind
  ...

For production:

- k3s
- k0s
  ...

And, of course, you can create separate nodes under one "machine." And use them as worker nodes, but the above solutions are simpler.